# Foreach Loop and If Statement

Tags: php

I have this foreach statement that is supposed to cycle through an array, but instead of outputting:

[checkbox] Something Here

It will instead output this:

[checkbox] [checkbox] Something here

Basically, the if statement isn't being skipped over, but the foreach loop is looking at the values in my array (in this case I only have 2 for testing purposes) and processing them at the same time instead of separately.  I've done some echo tests and that is what is happening, but why?

$blogID will have array values 56,57 so because the loop is processing both values at the same time, then both options in the if statement become true because 56 equals 56, but then 56 doesn't equal 57 on its 2nd pass so it will process the 2nd half of the if statement as true.  This is weird and I've never had this happen before.

Here is the code:

```
$getblog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' AND type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblog)){
$blogID = $row['id'];    
$tempData[$blogID][] = $row;

$data = $_REQUEST['blogIDS'];
$ids = explode(",", $data);

foreach($ids as $blogIDS) {
    $getblogids = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE id = '$blogIDS' AND type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogids)){
        $blogIDS = $row2['id'];    
        $tempData2[$blogIDS][] = $row2;
    }
}
    if ($row['id'] == $blogIDS) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$row['id']}' checked='yes'/>\n";
    } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$row['id']}'/>\n";
    }

    echo "<a class='heriyah_text1' href='manage_blogposts_add.php?resize=1&edit=1&id={$row['id']}&blogID={$_REQUEST['id']}&pageID={$_REQUEST['pageID']}&div={$_REQUEST['div']}'>{$row['title']}</a><p></p>\n";
}
```

Comment: Where's the *Something here* part? Also, your `elseif` is totally redundant. Simply use `else { echo ...`

Comment: The code above will always output two checkboxes in sequence.  Please post more of the surrounding code, because it isn't clear what is wrong here.

Comment: posted, I wasn't sure if that part was needed, but its up now!  Thanks for asking! =)

Comment: I can't duplicate your results using the code you've provided.  Please include your variables, in addition to the more code requested by Michael.

Comment: yes, that whole code is pretty confusing.  It took me a while to sit through it and write it out.  The while loop by itself works perfectly to get the individual data, but the foreach won't get me ONLY the checkbox I need.  It will give me two checkboxes, one I need and the other that I dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edited. try this and let me know:

```
$getblog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' AND 
                         type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblog)){
    $blogID = $row['blogID'];    
    $tempData[$blogID][] = $row;
}

$data = $_REQUEST['blogIDS'];
$ids = explode(",", $data);

foreach($ids as $blogID) {
    if (array_key_exists($blogID, $tempData)) {
        foreach($tempData[$blogID] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['blogID'] == $blogID) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$value['id']}' checked='yes'/>\n";
            } else {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$value['id']}'/>\n";
            }

            echo "<a class='heriyah_text1' href='manage_blogposts_add.php?resize=1&edit=1&id={$value['id']}&blogID={$_REQUEST['id']}&pageID={$_REQUEST['pageID']}&div={$_REQUEST['div']}'>{$value['title']}</a><p></p>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make any data show up now.  I wish I could just show you the page, but it's inside an admin panel of my CMS.  I'll keep messing around with it.  Is the $blogID value being changed alot?  you have `$ids as $blogID` which means one thing, but then we have $tempData[$blogID]` means something else.

Comment: okay I've gotten everything to show up now but it still doubles everything.  I just changed some values, check and see if what I did messed it up, I'm just gonna post it in my original question if that's okay with you.

Comment: i used $blogID as a key in $tempData. when you iterate through your ids you are accesses that particular key in $tempData. you need to be checking $blogID in $tempData otherwise this otherwise it's really no different than your first answer. you've edited your original post to iterate using $bID now instead which is producing the same results as before.

Comment: also, it may be helpful to see that your query is returning expected results. i would add a var_dump($getblog); immediately after your $getblog assignment. copy this query and execute it in mysql and make sure you're getting what you expect.

Comment: I'll definitely try that!  Let me see what I get!

Comment: i get this from the dump: `resource(6) of type (mysql result)` and when I paste my query into mySQL it returns 4 rows.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't looking closely. copy "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' AND 
                     type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC" and paste it into a var_dump for the query

Comment: Got back this: `string(99) "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blogID = '56' AND type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC"`  And also I pasted the query in phpMyAdmin MySQL and it came back with 4 records.

Comment: are you wanting results from each blogID? the first query is only returning results for a single blogID. how are `$_REQUEST['id']` the table column `blogID` and `$_REQUEST['blogIDs']` related? knowing the table structure and what exactly you are wanting to do would help.

Comment: Well the structure of my database is probably unconventional, but I put all of my content into one table and define what the object is by using the column called `type` and using numbers.  In this case a blog post is `5`. Here is what my database looks like: http://www.brockpatterson.com/database.png. As you can see in my database I have four posts already that have an type=5 and blogID=56.  So my query matches that: select all rows that have type=5 and blogID=56.  So yes, I am wanting to iterate the code for each post with the corresponding blogID.  blogIDS is an imploded list of data that...

Comment: I give to one database post that tells my CMS to post a blog with only those blog posts.  So what I am trying to do with the code I've posted to see which blog posts with the blogID=56 and type=5 and if they match blogIDS then put a check in the box, and if not leave the checkbox blank.

Comment: okay. it looks like you want to be checking equivalence to `blogID` and not `id` (`id` appears to be a unique identifier for `content` in this case) try my answer now.

Comment: I'm just gonna go in a different direction.  I don't think this can be done at all.  I appreciate your time and will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one instead:

```
$getblog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' AND 
                     type = '5' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblog)){
    $tempData[] = $row;
}

$data = $_REQUEST['blogIDS'];
$ids = explode(",", $data);

foreach($ids as $blogID) {
   foreach($tempData as $key => $value){
      if($value['id'] == $blogID){
         echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$value['id']}' checked='yes'/>\n";
      }else{
         echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='{$value['id']}'/>\n";
      }

      echo "<a class='heriyah_text1' href='manage_blogposts_add.php?resize=1&edit=1&id={$value['id']}&blogID={$_REQUEST['id']}&pageID={$_REQUEST['pageID']}&div={$_REQUEST['div']}'>{$value['title']}</a><p></p>\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that gets rid of the checkboxes doubling.  Was it because the foreach was inside the while loop?

Comment: It's causing this to happen though, I can probably figure it out, but maybe you can help while I try to figure it out. [CLICK HERE TO VIEW SCREENSHOT](http://www.brockpatterson.com/screen.png)

Comment: @drummer392, the doubling is caused due to the fact it's within the while loop. let me think of the current problem you've encountered with the updated codes. basically it should only show blog post 1 to 4 right?

Comment: Yes sir, I appologize for not knowing how to fix the problem further.  I have been learning PHP for the past 3 years now and still don't know how to do something like this.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: How many records does your query outputs? the 2nd foreach will loop through all the records from your query. The first foreach will loop through all the ids based on the $_REQUEST['blogIDS'] variable

Comment: From the $_REQUEST I receive just 2 records for this example. There will be more records in the future, so that means it will keep duplicating. I think the outer loop is causing it.